# How do I direct the login button to another page?

Tags: html, css, authentication, registration

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Welcome to Wave - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More</title>

    <style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:100,200,400);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700,400,300);

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;

    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.body{
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    right: -40px;
    bottom: -40px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url(http://ginva.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/city-skyline-wallpapers-008.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    z-index: 0;
}

.grad{
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    right: -40px;
    bottom: -40px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.header{
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 35px);
    left: calc(50% - 255px);
    z-index: 2;
}

.header div{
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.header div span{
    color: #5379fa !important;
}

.login{
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 75px);
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    height: 150px;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.login input[type=text]{
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 4px;
}

.login input[type=password]{
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.login input[type=button]{
    width: 260px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #a18d6c;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.login input[type=button]:hover{
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.login input[type=button]:active{
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.login input[type=text]:focus{
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

    enter code here

.login input[type=password]:focus{
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

.login input[type=button]:focus{
    outline: none;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder{
   color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

::-moz-input-placeholder{
   color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
</style>

    <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="body"></div>
        <div class="grad"></div>
        <div class="header">
            <div>Welcome to<span><br>Wave</span></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="login">
                <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="user"><br>
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>
                <input type="button" value="Login">
        </div>

  <script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>

    enter code here

</body>

</html>
```

How do I make the login button direct to another page? I am doing this for my class (High school) and need help. What do people need to login in. I have already completed a registration form.  I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Google it. You will get it. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Just add an "onclick" event to your button. Really you should add an ID to your button and break out the event into a separate JS script, but this would work for your purposes.

```
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="location.href = 'otherpage.html';">
```

Also definitely move all that style into a style.css file and then link it with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

That way you don't have it clogging up your html.

Answer (score 1):

You should send user's login information to a *server-side* script to be processed and then assign a *session* to that user.

Credentials checking and redirecting from JavaScript is not scure and an expert user can easily bypass this authentication phase. My suggestion is create a HTML form element and then submit those information to server side and from server, redirect the user to another page.

HTML Form:

```
<form action="address to server-side script" class="login" >
     <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="user"><br>
     <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="other page link" method="post">   
<div class="login">
   <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="user"><br>
   <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Login">
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="login"
    <form action="otherpage.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="user"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</div>
```

I hope this is useful for you.,